# Where is the JavaFX scene builder executable in Mac OSX for Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am creating a JavaFX 2 application using Intellij IDEA in Mac OSX and can't find the scene builder executable. My application runs fine but I am doing some complicated UI designs that I would like to be able to manipulate in scene builder. Do I need to install it manually? If so, where do I get the correct version of scene builder? I thought it was included with the JDK. I am using JDK 7u45.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to download Scene Builder manually. It is available on [JavaFX download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html). The stable version is 2.0, so you most probably want to use this version.

It is not bundled with JDK, most probably because of different licence.

It seems that the tool is going to be released as [source code only](https://dzone.com/articles/bye-bye-javafx-scene-builder).